# Where can I find IntelliJ's local file changes

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

IntelliJ just reverted all of my local changes when I moved the package that contained them. It refuses to undo the change because "other files changed in the meantime". IntelliJ must keep some sort of diff collection somewhere to back the undo command -- if I can find these diffs somewhere I can manually reapply my changes.

Where/how does IntelliJ store local changes to files and is it possible to access them outside of the "undo/redo" commands? Note that these are not the "local changes" via the version control plugin -- these are the local changes to a given file that you can iterate across using the undo/redo commands.

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.3.1.

<sub>(No, reverting via SVN will not work because I had not committed before moving the package. Yes, lesson learned, I will switch back to Eclipse after I reimplement my changes. Two of my coworkers also had this happen to them recently so clearly it's a bug.)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you haven't invalidated caches, you can look at a diff of your file changes underneath VCS > Local History > Show History.  And yes, changes which can be tracked across undo/redo phases can be kept here as well.

Highlight a file or folder in the project view to look at the changes made to the file or files, respectively.